# SQL totals by percentages calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I want a SQL query to go from

```
Shop    Regio    target1    sold1    target2    sold2 
shop1   regioA   6          3        10         5
shop2   regioA   4          2        4          2
shop3   regioB   6          0        3          0
shop4   regioC   9          9        8          8
shop5   regioB   8          4        2          1
```

to

```
regioC      100%
regioA       50%
regioB       25%
```

(nevermind the numbers, I just made these up)

I tried using this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT regio, SUM((sold2/target1)+(sold2/target2)) AS total 
FROM  `winkels` GROUP BY `regio` ORDER BY total DESC
```

Any ideas how to make it right?

Comment: can you try again to explain what you would like to calculate?  how do you arrive at 100%, 50% and 25%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.  You were trying to add percentages together, instead of dividing by the totals.

```
SELECT regio, 100*SUM(sold1+sold2)/sum(target1 +target2) AS total 
FROM  `winkels` GROUP BY `regio` ORDER BY total DESC
```